# TextBox hold last entered value

Tags: c#, wpf, get, set, popup

I have a project with Form and WPF(xaml) that popup with button click in the Form. The WPF have TextBoxes that the user can enter some values then to click to use these values in my project. what Im trying to achieve is that in the first call the user enter values and if he call it again, the TextBoxes shows the last entered values. Also I want to prevent the user from entered value for example here less than 1.

Here is my WPF code:

```
<Window x:Class="Alarms.AlarmsFC_Popup"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Alarms"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Alarms" Height="150" Width="525" Background="LightSteelBlue" Icon="warningred.ico">
    <Border Padding="10">
    <StackPanel>
            <!--IO Fields-->
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!--Begin Alarm-->
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 0 10 0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Number From" FontWeight="Black"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="BeginAlarmBox1" Padding="1" Margin="0 5 0 0" Background="White" Text="1"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>

                <!--End Alarm-->
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="0 0 0 0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Number To" FontWeight="Black"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="EndAlarmBox1" Padding="1" Margin="0 5 0 0" Background="White" Text="32"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

            <!--Buttons-->
            <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Name="BtnExport" Content="Export" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,10,10,0" Padding="8" Click="BtnExport_Click" />
                <Button Name="BtnCancel" Content="Cancel" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,0,0" Padding="8" Click="BtnCancel_Click" />
            </Grid>

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

And the code behind

```
public partial class AlarmsFC_Popup : Window
    {
        public AlarmsFC_Popup(int BAlarm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BeginAlarm = BAlarm;
        }
        public int BeginAlarm
        {
            get { return int.Parse(BeginAlarmBox1.Text); }
            set { 
                BeginAlarmBox1.Text = value.ToString();
                if (value < 1) MessageBox.Show("Value has to be 1 or higher!");
                }
        }
        private void BtnExport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(BeginAlarmBox1.Text)) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EndAlarmBox1.Text))
            {
                BeginAlarm = int.Parse(BeginAlarmBox1.Text);

                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Your for loop start at {0}", BeginAlarm.ToString()));
                    this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("One or more fields are empty. Fill all fields then press Export!");
            }

        }
        private void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("You clicked me at " + e.GetPosition(this).ToString());
        }
    }
```

Then I call it in my main Form

```
private void BtnAlarms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AlarmsFC_Popup Alarms = new AlarmsFC_Popup(1, 32);
            Alarms .ShowDialog();
            int FirstAlarm = Alarms .BeginAlarm;
        }
```

What I'm doing wrong? why it doesn't hold my last entered value, instead it always shows me 1 for the begin alarm

Comment: "Call" what again exactly? The `ShowDialog` method? You are creating a new instance of the window in your `BtnAlarms_Click` click event handler. You don't seem to store the values somewhere.

Comment: I thought with get/set will store my BeginAlarm value.

Comment: It's stored in the window instance that goes away and is eligible for garbage collection when you close it.

Comment: I believe its very simple, but I'm not able to find the way to do it. I only want to hold the BeginAlarm value as long as the Form is open. which means that if I open my window again, I see the last entered value.

Comment: If you hold on to the value "as long as the Form is open", how do you then expect to get it back once the form has been closed? Anyway, please refer to my answer.

Comment: If the form is closed. then it goes to default value "1". what I want is that the user run my program which will show the Form first. at the Form he has a button that open the window in order to enter value "BeginAlarm" that has value of 1. he can change it to another value and press ok. if he open the window agian he has to see the new entered value. and if he close the program and run it again he will see the defualt of 1.

Comment: See my answer for an example of how you could store the last value in a field.

Comment: but this is one way, right? I will not see the new entered value if I open the window again. It only save it.

Comment: If you don't want to see it,l you should replace replace `_beginAlarm` with `1` on the first line in the event handler in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the value somewhere, otherwise it goes away once you close the window.

You could for example do this using a private field in the main window:

```
int _beginAlarm = 1;
private void BtnAlarms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AlarmsFC_Popup Alarms = new AlarmsFC_Popup(_beginAlarm, 32);
    Alarms.ShowDialog();
    _beginAlarm = Alarms.BeginAlarm;
}
```